# How to display average date in list view?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a list with a Date and Time column (date only). I would like to get the average date for all items in the list

I have selected Average for the field in the view settings under Totals however the value on the view just displays the count, not an average

Is there an OOTB way to get the average for all items' darte field values returned as a date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there is no OOB way to get the average of the date column for all items and return as a date.

There is a workaround for the issue. We can export the list to the excel and calculate date average for the date column.

There is a similar post.

https://superuser.com/questions/911464/calculate-date-average-in-excel